# How to hide/unhide other applications icon?

Tags: android

I am developing a small application i.e AppHider
In this i get the list of user installed applications and their launcher name also by getting their package name

Now i want to hide/unhide the application, I used this code below but it is not working, so can anyone tell please, how can I hide/unhide the application icon of other apps

for hiding app icon

```
PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
                    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(SingleAppActivity.this, applauncher); // activity which is first time open in manifiest file which is declare as <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

for unhidding app icon

```
            PackageManager p = getPackageManager();
            ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(SingleAppActivity.this, applauncher);
            p.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
```

Comment: What issue you are facing with this code ?

Comment: @Prince it is not hiding the application icon

Comment: do a little search on Google Play and you will see that all other apps that do this same function requires root. So you won't be able to do without it.

Answer (score 1):

you have to add package name instead of classname.this see below code

Replace your

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName(SingleAppActivity.this, applauncher);
```

with

```
ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("apppackagename","apppackagename.launcher classname");
```

Thats it...