# Hide apps from the launcher programmatically on a rooted device?

Tags: android, root

I want to programmatically hide **another apps** form the launcher, I know that this is possible because [this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phongphan.disableapp) does it(also when is installed as user app). I have a rooted device and can use RootTools library.

Up to now, I have done this(without success):

In MainActivity's onCreate:

```
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("ar.com.luzzatto.linterna","MainActivity.launcher classname");
    pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName,PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP);
    Toast.makeText(this, "DONE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

On the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE"/>
```

**It's very important to say that I put my app on /system/priv-app in order to get system permissions.** I don't gen any error and the TOAST shows, but the other app icon keeps showing(as usual) on the phone's launcher.

Another thing that I want to clarify is that the app I want to mimic([this app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.phongphan.disableapp)) doesn't need to be put on /system/priv-app and does the job very well. So my manin intention is to know how **that app** works. But meanwhile, if anyone has another idea(also if I have to be on /priv-app) will be welcome.

Comment: what have you done so far? welcome to sof

Comment: Almost nothing, I only have a Hello world app with the RootTools lib.

Comment: Well then, before asking any further questions, google how to do get this done. And if you're stuck anywhere, ask again :)

Comment: I googled and also reviewed lot of Stackoverflow q&a, and folowed some like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24952223/how-to-hide-unhide-other-applications-icon and but without success.

Comment: I meant that MY APP is almost in hello world state.

Comment: Okay, but what have you done in order to hide the application icon of other apps from the launcher?

Comment: First check if the device is rooted. Then try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19114439/android-hide-unhide-app-icon-programmatically